# Sync user folders between computers

Tags: sync, multiple-computers

Is there a way I can sync the entire user folders (Documents, Pictures, Music, Videos etc.) between 2 computers? I don't want to use Dropbox (or any similar single folder syncing service) as I have a large number of files and am forced to move everything in Dropbox.

Ideally i would like to maintain the structure on my desktop and have those files available on my laptop.

Both of my computers are running Windows 8.1 Pro.

Comment: Use OneDrive a native facility in Windows 8.1. You need a Microsoft account. Just type onedrive on the start screen and you will find it.

Comment: but OneDrive only sync the OneDrive folder, like dropbox. i want to sync my Documents, Pictures and etc without having to move them all to the OneDrive/DropBox Folder

Comment: You can use a junction point

Answer (score 4):

If these two computer exist within the same network, you could setup a network share and change the location that these folders are pointing to on each computer (either manually by going into the users directory (In the Explorer Address bar, while logged into the user in question, type %USERPROFILE%) or through GPO).

It's worth noting that the following will only work if both computers remain on the same network (whether that is through a VPN or locally doesn't matter). The second you try accessing your documents on the laptop away from the network that your desktop is on, you will run into problems.

On your desktop:

1. Click Start
2. Open Control Panel
3. Open the Network and Sharing Center
4. Open Advanced Sharing Settings (In the left hand side bar)

Under Home or Work

1. Enable Network Discovery
2. Enable File and Printer Sharing
3. Hit Save Changes

Close the currently open window.

1. Open Explorer (Computer)
2. In the address bar, type %USERPROFILE%
3. Hit enter
4. Right click My Documents
5. Go to properties
6. Click on the Sharing Tab
7. Click the share button
8. Determine how you'd like to setup your sharing permissions (Outside
   the scope of this question)
9. Click Share
10. Click Close

On your laptop:

1. Click Start
2. Open Control Panel
3. Open the Network and Sharing Center
4. Open Advanced Sharing Settings (In the left hand side bar)

Under Home or Work

1. Enable Network Discovery
2. Enable File and Printer Sharing
3. Hit Save Changes

Close the currently open window.

1. Open Explorer (Computer)
2. In the tree-list on the left hand side, navigate to Computer
3. Click Map Network Drive in the action bar under the address bar
4. Hit browse
5. Select the share you'd like to map from your desktop
6. Hit Ok
7. Hit Finish

Test to make sure you have access to the new drive

1. In the address bar, type %USERPROFILE%
2. Hit enter
3. Right click My Documents
4. Go to properties
5. Click the Location Tab
6. Click the Move button
7. Navigate to your newly created drive
8. Click Select Folder

It will prompt you asking if you'd like to merge your folders, I'd recommend it.

Repeat these directions for any of the other user folders you'd like to remap.

More Information:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732275.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can use SyncToy to sync your entire folder, and its Free from microsoft. Check [this](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15155) out.

Or, you can use Onedrive, GoogleDrive too. It just like a dropbox. :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use [sugarsync](https://www.sugarsync.com/) to sync everything you want without having to copy everything.

Update-1:

[Sync](https://www.getsync.com/) also syncs devices with the added advantage of not having to store them in the cloud

Comment: hmm. sugar sync looks interesting. is there a free alternative? i don't have to necessarily have the files available online. just them synced between my computers

Comment: Abhishek see my edit

Answer (score 1):

> hmm. sugar sync looks interesting. is there a free alternative? i
>   don't have to necessarily have the files available online. just them
>   synced between my computers

Free alternative for sugar sync or dropbox is the [basefolder](http://www.basefolder.com), this application will allow its users to access their home computer files from anywhere. Your all files will be saved on your home system. It also provides optional cloud storage.

Answer (score 0):

[basefolder](http://www.basefolder.com/) and [sugar sync](https://www.sugarsync.com/) applications looks far better than other backup services, as we see in basefolder its users can save their files on home system and access it from anywhere, and it is faster than other services as i observed.

Comment: basefolder is not surely the service that the OP is looking for. It allows you to access a particular set of files that you share with basefolder.com.... Not an answer - I think. Sugarsync link seems to be broken